# In useEffect, the state value is called several times to use the Math function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, math, react-hooks, frontend

Run setRandomImgNum in useEffect randomly using Math.floor function. However, if you take a look at randomImgNum with the console, useEffect is not called once, but multiple times.

Why is the randomImgNum value printed out multiple times? How can I make it call only once?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Load() {
  const [randomImgNum, setRandomImgNum] = useState<number>(1);
  const [randomTxtNum, setRandomTxtNum] = useState<number>(1); 

  useEffect(() => {
        setRandomImgNum(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1);
        let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
        if (randomImgNum == 1) {
            setRandomTxtNum(randNum % 6 + 1)
        } else if (randomImgNum == 2) {
            setRandomTxtNum(randNum % 9 + 1)
        } else if (randomImgNum == 3) {
            setRandomTxtNum(randNum % 5 + 1)
        }
  }, [setRandomTxtNum, setRandomImgNum]);
  console.log(randomImgNum) // 2 2 4 1 2 3 
 
return (
   <>
   </>
 )
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve] sufficient enough to see why this component is rendering/mounting more than expected. You'll want to also move the console log into a `useEffect` hook to get a more accurate measure how often the component really renders and the `useEffect` hook is called.

Comment: @DrewReese It's corrected.

Comment: This looks like correct code to me. The only thing is that you're checking the value of `randomImgNum` and this will always be `1` since the state does not update immediately

Comment: FWIW I have copy pasted your code into a running [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/in-useeffect-the-state-value-is-called-several-times-to-use-the-math-function-wqn2g1), fixed the logging issue, and see an accurate number of render logs. (1) initial log mount, (2) remount because `React.StrictMode` component, and then (3) the rerender from the enqueued state update from (1). I can't reproduce the issue as you describe.